# Git commit, `no such file or directory`?

Tags: xcode, git

I've deleted some files from my project, but they still show in the commit screen with a `D` symbol next to them.

When I try to commit I get the error .... no such file or directory, how can I remove these files aka get rid of the warning ?

Comment: how do you delete these files

Comment: I deleted them from my project. However source control is still showing them.

Comment: @Jules Can you link to a gist of the output of git status? It sounds like some of your paths are messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The D means deleted. Git still knows about a file if you delete a file with rm or via the finder. To remove a file from git and from disk:

```
git rm <filename>
git commit -m "message"
```

Comment: I'm getting did not match any files.

Answer (score 1):

In git when you add changes to the staging area (prior to committing) changes that removed a file are not staged by default. Using `--all`, `-A`, or `--no-ignore-removal` options with your `git add <filename>` will stage all types of changes.

ie. `git add . --all` will stage all changes before you commit, including deleted file changes.

Alternatively, as mentioned by Dau in his answer if you use `git rm <filename>` and git remove the file from the working tree and from the index.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, it seems that git isn't aware of the file, ie: the file isn't *staged* in the index. Try running this serie of commands :

```
git add <filename> // stage the file
git rm --cached <filename>
```

Maybe you simply deleted the file using some kind of `rm <filename>`, in that case try to check out the file first, and then try the removal.

```
git checkout HEAD -- <filename>
git rm <filename>
```

Comment: I'm assuming I need to use terminal to do this. Is it enough to go into my project folder, how do I associate with the current git database?

Comment: inside your project's directory, you'll see a hidden directory `.git`. Yes it is enough to `cd` to the project directory, and then try these commands.